How to match my signal active mode with Desktop mode?
So what I'm trying to do is to change my resolution desktop by 1680 x 1050
I'm using Custom Resolution Utility (CRU) because my AMD Software doesn't have the features to create new resolution (can anyone explain why this happen?)
AMD Software no features to create new resolution
So the main problem here is, my active signal mode doesn't match with desktop mode here is the picture
Active signal mode not matched with dekstop mode
my laptop spec:
Nvidia RTX 3050 and AMD Ryzen 7 6000
I have tried to turn off my GPU Scalling in AMD Software but it still not working.
GPU Scalling Off
Is there anything i can do to fix this issues?

What model is your monitor? Are you using the latest NVIDIA driver and did you do a clean installation (link)? And most important: Why are you forcing a display mode that is not natural for your monitor?
